# schema.org markup for a product with two prices: normal price and reduced price

Tags: schema.org

I can't find the `itemprop`s for a product with two prices on schema.org.

The types of prices are:

1. an old price
2. a new reduced price

I can't imagine, that there is not fitting schema.org markup for this, but after a long search, I couldn't find the solution for this anywhere.

Example HTML:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <!-- ... -->

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <!-- What should I use for the old price? -->
    <div><span itemprop="???">4321</span> <span>€</span></div>

    <!-- Should I use "price" for the new reduced price? -->
    <div><span itemprop="price">1234</span> <span>€</span></div>

  </div>

  <!-- ... -->

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe give two prices, and use `validFrom`/`validThrough` on them …? http://schema.org/PriceSpecification

Comment: I guess, that would be the right way to go. Can you write it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give two prices, and use `validFrom`/`validThrough` on them …?

http://schema.org/PriceSpecification